# Z-Axis raising and dropping substantially during print knocking print off

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting

I've had my Creality Ender 3 Pro since October 2019. It was running like a dream until about a month ago. The Z-axis started knocking prints off the plate during printing. I've changed mats and worked on adhesion issues. I've switched to a glass plate and triple checked that it is level. I checked to see if it was binding but honestly I couldn't tell.

I'm at a loss of what to do to troubleshoot and fix the issue. Any suggestions?

It homes fine and manual controls work fine with no issues.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the "Z axis knocking prints off"? What part actually collides or moves in a manner that's unexpected/erroneous?

Comment: can you check if your Potal (X-Axis) is orthogonal to the vertical bars? knocking it off is a known issiue.

Comment: Did you ever find out what happened? Please add an answer if you did!

Comment: did you get an answer to this? I'm having the same issue and the z axis keeps dropping during prints at regular intervals above a certain height, as if it can't hold itself up (all screws seem to be right, and there's no binding it just isn't holding itself at the right height)?

Answer (score 2):

Can you send a link to a short video of the problem occuring? It might be because of multiple factors but we will be able to identify if there's a video of it.

Possible reasons:

- Z axis nut might be too tight. This would cause the nut to bind with the leadscrew and so the motor will not be able to lift the z-axis further while printing.
- Not enough retraction. This would cause filament to ooze from the nozzle during travel moves and this filament would collide with the printed object, causing it to be knocked off. A possible solution for this would be to enable Z-hop in the slider, have the hop distance set to at least 1.5x the layer height you are currently printing with.
- Too small of a contact area. This usually happens more often for tall prints. A solution would be to increase brim in the slicer settings (at least 10~15 lines) to increase the adhesion of the print and the bed.
- Dirty nozzle. Old prints filament may be stuck on the outer face of the nozzle and might be catching onto the printed part while printing.